# `npm help X` just lists commands that match X

Tags: node.js, npm

For example:

`$ npm help prune
Top hits for "prune"
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
npm help prune                                                           prune:3
npm help index                                                           prune:2
npm apihelp prune                                                        prune:2
npm help ls                                                              prune:1
npm help rm                                                              prune:1
npm help uninstall                                                       prune:1
npm help removing-npm                                                    prune:1
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————`

How do I get npm to actually *show me the help page*?

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem accessing the NPM `man` pages on your system.

`npm <command> --help` will at least give you simple usage for the command.

Running `man npm` or `man npm-prune` might give you some more detail on the issue. You might be missing `man` completely or the NPM man pages. Maybe the package you used to install NPM had an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Ubuntu's woefully out-of-date `apt` version of npm was superseding my manually-installed up-to-date version. Running `apt-get purge nodejs npm` solved the problem.